# How does flutter get the main color captured in the camera？

Tags: flutter, colors, camera

I'm building an app that uses a camera to capture pictures, and I need to prevent the lens from being blocked and display all black.
I'm using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) library.

```
  Future<void> initController() async {
    try {
      List cameras = await availableCameras();
      controller = CameraController(cameras.first, ResolutionPreset.low);
      await controller!.initialize();
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((onValue) {
        controller!.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch);
      });
      controller!.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
        image = img;
      });
    } on Exception {
      print(Exception);
    }
  }
```

I hope to use the CameraImage type that comes with the library to obtain the color code in some way in startImageStream to determine whether the user blocks the camera.